# TypeError: jQuery(...).tpessential is not a function

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress, revolution-slider

I installed Rev Slider and Essential Grid plugin. However, I got this error:

> message: TypeError: jQuery(...).tpessential is not a function.

When I deactivated Rev Slider, Ess Grid plugin works again. I tried to remove and re-install Rev Slider but it doesn't work.

Hope anyone can help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are missing some sort of dependency or your version of JQuery is not up to date.

Comment: jQuery is up to date.